# get dynamic bool variable from another class iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I have Location Tracking class and another class with listing. I need to check if locationService is running when entering listView. In the locationService class I've added boolean to track service start and stop. But I can't track this boolean variable from listView class.

here is my code how I am doing now, but it takes only initial value of the locationService class

```
//listView.m

@property (strong,nonatomic) LocationTracker * trackerClass;


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  self.trackerClass = [[LocationTracker alloc] init];

  if([self.trackerClass getTrackerStatus]==1)
    NSLog(@"LOCATION SERVICE STATUS IS RUNNING");
   else 
    NSLog(@"LOCATION SERVICE STATUS IS STOPPED");
}


//locationService.h

     @property (nonatomic, readwrite) int trackerStatus;
     - (int)getTrackerStatus;

//locationService.m

- (void)stopLocationTracking {_trackerStatus=0;}
- (void)startLocationTracking {_trackerStatus=1;}


- (int)getTrackerStatus{
    return _trackerStatus;
}
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you want a notification of when _trackerStatus changes. You should fire some sort of Event. Consider looking at the delegate pattern for ObjC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set this boolean variable as a local variable and create a simple static getter to get this bool. your LocationTracker will change the value of the variable and you can get it from anywhere.

```
@implementation LocationTracker

BOOL isStart;

//Dont forget to delclear this methode in the .h file
+(BOOL)isStart{
    return isStart;
}

your code...
```

Any where in your app just import your calss and wirte:

```
BOOL isStart = [LocationTracker isStart];
//The getting vaiable should be the updated bool in you LocationTracker class
```

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting

```
- (int)getTrackerStatus{
    return _trackerStatus;
}
```

Comment: You should probably improve your answer by explaining why this may solve the problem.

Comment: I first wanted to see if it works. If it does I will write a lot more details.